# Filter record from dynamically generated table to update in angular

Tags: angular

I am trying to implement the update functionality for the dynamically generated table. I have assigned unique id to the tds. Now When the user hits the save button, I calling the update method by passing the unique id.

If you see the update method in the component code, I am trying to pass the object FundClass. I need to derive the values which are currently in FundClasses object. As you can see in the JSON structure , the fundClasses object contains FundDetailsviewmodel which further down contains FundClassDetailsViewModel.

FundClasses - > FundDetailsviewmodel -> FundClassDetailsViewModel

The fundclass object would contain values from a single array element of the FundClassDetailsViewModel object. I need to filter this object based on the id that i am passing to the update method.

I have also shared the structure of the object while debugging. So in the screenshot below if the id is 305583 , it should fetch that record and assign it to the FundClass object.

[image]

Json structure

```
{"FundDetailsViewModel":[{"CogencyClasses":[{"Id":1121,"FundId":652,"ShareClass":"Class B","LocalCurrency":"USD","Name":"Class B USD"}],"FundClassDetailsViewModel":[{"Id":305583,"Description":null,"InvestedAmount":900000,"InceptionDate":null,"LegalFundClassId":13713,"LegalFundClassName":"Class A","DataReference":null,"CogencyClassId":null,"CogencyClassName":null,"ClosureStatusId":103,"ClosureStatusName":"In Liquidation","IsSidePocket":true,"IsThematic":true,"VehicleTypeId":1,"VehicleTypeName":"FX Trade","FundId":237146,"FundName":"P Sylebra Ltd."},{"Id":250028,"Description":"Class A","InvestedAmount":23732600,"InceptionDate":null,"LegalFundClassId":13713,"LegalFundClassName":"Class A","DataReference":null,"CogencyClassId":1121,"CogencyClassName":null,"ClosureStatusId":null,"ClosureStatusName":null,"IsSidePocket":false,"IsThematic":false,"VehicleTypeId":null,"VehicleTypeName":null,"FundId":237146,"FundName":"P Sylebra Ltd."},{"Id":250029,"Description":"Class B","InvestedAmount":119307314,"InceptionDate":null,"LegalFundClassId":13717,"LegalFundClassName":"Class B","DataReference":null,"CogencyClassId":null,"CogencyClassName":null,"ClosureStatusId":null,"ClosureStatusName":null,"IsSidePocket":false,"IsThematic":false,"VehicleTypeId":null,"VehicleTypeName":null,"FundId":237146,"FundName":"P Sylebra Ltd."},{"Id":250030,"Description":"Class B1","InvestedAmount":null,"InceptionDate":"2014-05-01T00:00:00","LegalFundClassId":13716,"LegalFundClassName":"Class B1","DataReference":null,"CogencyClassId":null,"CogencyClassName":null,"ClosureStatusId":null,"ClosureStatusName":null,"IsSidePocket":false,"IsThematic":false,"VehicleTypeId":null,"VehicleTypeName":null,"FundId":237146,"FundName":"P Sylebra Ltd."},{"Id":250031,"Description":"Class C","InvestedAmount":null,"InceptionDate":"2014-07-31T00:00:00","LegalFundClassId":13715,"LegalFundClassName":"Class C","DataReference":null,"CogencyClassId":null,"CogencyClassName":null,"ClosureStatusId":null,"ClosureStatusName":null,"IsSidePocket":false,"IsThematic":false,"VehicleTypeId":null,"VehicleTypeName":null,"FundId":237146,"FundName":"P Sylebra Ltd."},{"Id":250032,"Description":"Class D","InvestedAmount":null,"InceptionDate":"2014-07-31T00:00:00","LegalFundClassId":13714,"LegalFundClassName":"Class D","DataReference":null,"CogencyClassId":null,"CogencyClassName":null,"ClosureStatusId":null,"ClosureStatusName":null,"IsSidePocket":false,"IsThematic":false,"VehicleTypeId":null,"VehicleTypeName":null,"FundId":237146,"FundName":"P Sylebra Ltd."},{"Id":305581,"Description":"T","InvestedAmount":null,"InceptionDate":null,"LegalFundClassId":13713,"LegalFundClassName":"Class A","DataReference":null,"CogencyClassId":null,"CogencyClassName":null,"ClosureStatusId":null,"ClosureStatusName":null,"IsSidePocket":false,"IsThematic":false,"VehicleTypeId":null,"VehicleTypeName":null,"FundId":237146,"FundName":"P Sylebra Ltd."}],"PrimaryLegalFundClasses":[{"Id":237146,"Description":"Class A","ClassType":3},{"Id":237146,"Description":"Class B","ClassType":3},{"Id":237146,"Description":"Class B1","ClassType":3},{"Id":237146,"Description":"Class C","ClassType":3},{"Id":237146,"Description":"Class D","ClassType":3}]},{"CogencyClasses":[{"Id":0,"FundId":0,"ShareClass":"Assign Cogency Fund First","LocalCurrency":null,"Name":"Assign Cogency Fund First "}],"FundClassDetailsViewModel":[{"Id":100541,"Description":"Class A","InvestedAmount":null,"InceptionDate":null,"LegalFundClassId":11167,"LegalFundClassName":"Class A","DataReference":null,"CogencyClassId":null,"CogencyClassName":null,"ClosureStatusId":null,"ClosureStatusName":null,"IsSidePocket":false,"IsThematic":false,"VehicleTypeId":null,"VehicleTypeName":null,"FundId":5508,"FundName":"Sylebra Capital Partners (Offshore) Ltd"},{"Id":250033,"Description":"Class B","InvestedAmount":null,"InceptionDate":null,"LegalFundClassId":11166,"LegalFundClassName":"Class B","DataReference":null,"CogencyClassId":null,"CogencyClassName":null,"ClosureStatusId":null,"ClosureStatusName":null,"IsSidePocket":false,"IsThematic":false,"VehicleTypeId":null,"VehicleTypeName":null,"FundId":5508,"FundName":"Sylebra Capital Partners (Offshore) Ltd"}],"PrimaryLegalFundClasses":[{"Id":5508,"Description":"Class A","ClassType":1},{"Id":5508,"Description":"Class B","ClassType":1}]}],"VehicleTypes":[{"Id":108,"Spf":false,"Name":"Secondaries","SortOrder":null,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Id":100,"Spf":false,"Name":"Co-Investment (non-SPF)","SortOrder":1,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":true,"IsCardiff":true},{"Id":1,"Spf":false,"Name":"FX Trade","SortOrder":2,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Id":3,"Spf":false,"Name":"Listed ETF","SortOrder":3,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Id":4,"Spf":false,"Name":"Listed Security","SortOrder":4,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Id":2,"Spf":false,"Name":"Mutual Fund","SortOrder":5,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Id":5,"Spf":false,"Name":"Offshore Fund","SortOrder":6,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Id":6,"Spf":false,"Name":"Onshore US - 40 Act Fund","SortOrder":7,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Id":9,"Spf":false,"Name":"Onshore US Non - 40 Act Fund","SortOrder":8,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Id":8,"Spf":false,"Name":"EnTrustPermal Product","SortOrder":9,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Id":7,"Spf":true,"Name":"EnTrustPermal SPF - Standard","SortOrder":10,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":true,"IsCardiff":false},{"Id":105,"Spf":true,"Name":"EnTrustPermal SPF – 40 Act","SortOrder":10,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Id":106,"Spf":true,"Name":"EnTrustPermal SPF – UCITS","SortOrder":10,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Id":102,"Spf":true,"Name":"EnTrustPermal SPF - Blocker","SortOrder":10,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Id":103,"Spf":true,"Name":"EnTrustPermal SPF - Co-Investment","SortOrder":10,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":true,"IsCardiff":true},{"Id":104,"Spf":true,"Name":"EnTrustPermal SPF - Special Sit","SortOrder":10,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":true,"IsCardiff":true},{"Id":10,"Spf":false,"Name":"Private Equity","SortOrder":11,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":true,"IsCardiff":false},{"Id":101,"Spf":false,"Name":"Side-Pocket","SortOrder":12,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":true,"IsCardiff":false},{"Id":11,"Spf":false,"Name":"Special Situation (non-SPF)","SortOrder":13,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":true,"IsCardiff":true},{"Id":12,"Spf":false,"Name":"Third Party Fund of Funds","SortOrder":14,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Id":13,"Spf":false,"Name":"UCITS","SortOrder":15,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false},{"Id":14,"Spf":false,"Name":"Other","SortOrder":50,"AumReadOnly":false,"PerformanceReadOnly":false,"BloombergTickerRequired":false,"ClassLevel":false,"IsCardiff":false}],"ClosureStatuses":[{"Id":110,"Name":"Hard Closed","IsActive":true,"SortOrder":null},{"Id":111,"Name":"Open","IsActive":true,"SortOrder":null},{"Id":112,"Name":"Soft Closed","IsActive":true,"SortOrder":null},{"Id":1,"Name":"Open - to all","IsActive":true,"SortOrder":1},{"Id":2,"Name":"Open - to Permal only","IsActive":true,"SortOrder":2},{"Id":3,"Name":"Closed - hard","IsActive":true,"SortOrder":3},{"Id":104,"Name":"Closed - with wait list","IsActive":true,"SortOrder":4},{"Id":100,"Name":"Closed - but will reopen","IsActive":true,"SortOrder":5},{"Id":21,"Name":"Closed - but replacing redemptions","IsActive":true,"SortOrder":6},{"Id":101,"Name":"Redemptions Gated","IsActive":true,"SortOrder":7},{"Id":102,"Name":"Redemptions Suspended","IsActive":true,"SortOrder":8},{"Id":103,"Name":"In Liquidation","IsActive":true,"SortOrder":9}]}
```

I have written an update method which takes id parameter sent when clicking the save method. How do I filter FundClassDetailsViewModel object and assign it to the this.FundClass . I am referring to this statement in the component code

```
this.FundClass = this.FundClasses.FundDetailsViewModel.FundClassDetailsViewModel;
```

Component

```
 import {Component, OnInit, Input} from '@angular/core';
import { TermsService } from '../../services/terms.service';
import { NotifyService } from '../../utilities/notify.service';


@Component({
selector : 'mgr-fund-classes',
templateUrl : './fundClasses.component.html'
})


export class FundClassesComponent implements OnInit {

    private _fundClasses : any;
    FundClass : any;
    public fundClassKeys = [];
    public EditMode: any = {};

    public get FundClasses(): any {
        return this._fundClasses;
    }
    @Input()
    public set FundClasses(value: any) {
        this._fundClasses = value;
    }

    constructor(private termsService: TermsService, private notify: NotifyService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.init();
    }

    buttonClicked(id) {
       this.EditMode[id] = !this.EditMode[id];
    }

    Update(id) {

              this.FundClass = this.FundClasses.FundDetailsViewModel.FundClassDetailsViewModel;

              this.termsService.updateFundClasses(this.FundClass).then((result) => {
                if (result) {
                    this.notify.success('Fund Class Details Successfully Updated');
                    this.EditMode = !this.EditMode;
                   // this.managerStrategyDetailsEvent.next('getTermsDetails');
                    }
                }) .catch(err => {
                    this.notify.error('An Error Has Occured While Updating Fund Class Details');
                });
        }


    init() {

    }
```

Html

```
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="chk" style="width: 13px; height: 13px;" />
    <label for="chk">Invested</label>

</div>

<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header panel-heading">
        <span class="left-label" style="font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold; ">Fund Classes</span>
        <div class="pull-right" style="padding-right:10px; display: inline-block; vertical-align:middle">
            <label style="text-align: center; vertical-align:middle" class="btn btn-default pull-right"> <i
                    data-bind="visible: true" class="fa fa-plus-square"></i><input type="checkbox" class="hidden" /> Add
                Class</label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div *ngIf="FundClasses && FundClasses.FundDetailsViewModel">

        <table class="fundClassesTable table-striped">

            <tr>
                <th class="tableItem bold">Fund Name</th>
                <th class="tableItem bold">Accounting Class Name</th>
                <th class="tableItem bold">Class ID</th>
                <th class="tableItem bold">Legal Fund Class</th>
                <th class="tableItem bold">Inception Date</th>
                <th class="tableItem bold">Invested Amount</th>
                <th class="tableItem bold">Vehicle Type</th>
                <th class="tableItem bold">Closure Status</th>
                <th class="tableItem bold">Is Side Pocket?</th>
                <th class="tableItem bold">Is Thematic?</th>
                <th class="tableItem bold">Cogency Class?</th>
                <th class="tableItem"></th>
            </tr>

            <ng-container *ngFor="let fundClass of FundClasses.FundDetailsViewModel">
                <tr *ngFor="let f of fundClass['FundClassDetailsViewModel'] | keyvalue">
                    <td class="tableItem">{{ f.value.FundName}}</td>
                    <td class="tableItem">{{ f.value.Description}}</td>
                    <td class="tableItem">{{f.value.Id}}</td>
                    <td *ngIf="EditMode[f.value.Id]" class="tableItem">
                        <kendo-dropdownlist style="width:100%" [(ngModel)]="f.value.LegalFundClassId"
                            class="form-control  form-control-sm" [data]="fundClass.PrimaryLegalFundClasses"
                            [filterable]="false" textField="Description" [valuePrimitive]="true" valueField="Id">
                        </kendo-dropdownlist>
                    </td>
                    <td [attr.id]="'f.value.Id'" *ngIf="!EditMode[f.value.Id]" class="tableItem" style="width:100%">
                        {{ f.value.LegalFundClassName}}
                    </td>
                    <td [attr.id]="'f.value.Id'" *ngIf="EditMode[f.value.Id]" class="tableItem">
                        <kendo-datepicker style="width:100%" [format]="'MMMM yyyy'" [topView]="'decade'"
                            [bottomView]="'year'" [(ngModel)]="f.value.InceptionDate"
                            class="form-control  form-control-sm">
                        </kendo-datepicker>
                    </td>
                    <td [attr.id]="'f.value.Id'" *ngIf="!EditMode[f.value.Id]" class="tableItem" style="width:100%">
                        {{ f.value.InceptionDate | date:"'MMMM yyyy"}}
                    </td>
                    <td [attr.id]="'f.value.Id'" *ngIf="EditMode[f.value.Id]" class="tableItem" style="width:100%">
                        <input kendoTextBox [(ngModel)]="f.value.InvestedAmount"
                            style="width: 284px; height: 29.5px;" />
                    </td>
                    <td [attr.id]="'f.value.Id'" *ngIf="!EditMode[f.value.Id]" class="tableItem" style="width:100%">
                        {{ f.value.InvestedAmount | number : '.2-2'}}
                    </td>
                    <td [attr.id]="'f.value.Id'" *ngIf="EditMode[f.value.Id]" class="tableItem">
                        <kendo-dropdownlist style="width:100%" [(ngModel)]="f.value.VehicleTypeId"
                            class="form-control  form-control-sm" [data]="FundClasses.VehicleTypes" [filterable]="false"
                            textField="Name" [valuePrimitive]="true" valueField="Id"></kendo-dropdownlist>
                    </td>
                    <td [attr.id]="'f.value.Id'" *ngIf="!EditMode[f.value.Id]" class="tableItem" style="width:100%">
                        {{ f.value.VehicleTypeName}}
                    </td>
                    <td [attr.id]="'f.value.Id'" *ngIf="EditMode[f.value.Id]" class="tableItem">
                        <kendo-dropdownlist style="width:100%" [(ngModel)]="f.value.ClosureStatusId"
                            class="form-control  form-control-sm" [data]="FundClasses.ClosureStatuses"
                            [filterable]="false" textField="Name" [valuePrimitive]="true" valueField="Id">
                        </kendo-dropdownlist>
                    </td>
                    <td [attr.id]="'f.value.Id'" *ngIf="!EditMode[f.value.Id]" class="tableItem" style="width:100%">
                        {{ f.value.ClosureStatusName}}
                    </td>
                    <td [attr.id]="'f.value.Id'" *ngIf="EditMode[f.value.Id]" class="tableItem">
                        <input type="checkbox" value="{{f.value.IsSidePocket}}" id="chk"
                            style="width: 13px; height: 13px;" />
                        <label for="chk">Yes</label>

                    </td>
                    <td [attr.id]="'f.value.Id'" *ngIf="!EditMode[f.value.Id]" class="tableItem" style="width:100%">
                        {{ f.value.IsSidePocket == true ? 'Yes' : 'No'}}
                    </td>
                    <td [attr.id]="'f.value.Id'" *ngIf="EditMode[f.value.Id]" class="tableItem">
                        <input type="checkbox" value="{{f.value.IsThematic}}" style="width: 13px; height: 13px;" />
                        <label for="chk">Yes</label>
                    </td>
                    <td [attr.id]="'f.value.Id'" *ngIf="!EditMode[f.value.Id]" class="tableItem" style="width:100%">
                        {{ f.value.IsThematic == true ? 'Yes' : 'No'}}
                    </td>
                    <td [attr.id]="'f.value.Id'" *ngIf="EditMode[f.value.Id]" class="tableItem">
                        <kendo-dropdownlist style="width:100%" [(ngModel)]="f.value.CogencyClassId"
                            class="form-control  form-control-sm" [data]="fundClass.CogencyClasses" [filterable]="false"
                            textField="Name" [valuePrimitive]="true" valueField="Id"></kendo-dropdownlist>
                    </td>
                    <td [attr.id]="'f.value.Id'" *ngIf="!EditMode[f.value.Id]" class="tableItem" style="width:100%">
                        {{ f.value.CogencyClassId}}
                    </td>
                    <td class="tableItem">

                        <button *ngIf="!EditMode[f.value.Id]" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn mr-1 col-sm-4"
                            (click)="buttonClicked(f.value.Id)">Edit</button>
                        <button *ngIf="EditMode[f.value.Id]" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn mr-1 col-sm-3"
                            (click)="buttonClicked(f.value.Id)">Save</button>
                        <button *ngIf="EditMode[f.value.Id]" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn mr-1  col-sm-3"
                            (click)="buttonClicked(f.value.Id)">Delete</button>
                        <button *ngIf="EditMode[f.value.Id]" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn mr-1  col-sm-3"
                            (click)="buttonClicked(f.value.Id)">Cancel</button>

                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ng-container>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried this but it doesnt work

```
  this.FundClass = this.FundClasses.FundDetailsViewModel.array.forEach(x => {
              x.Id = id;
          });
```

Comment: I would need to get all FundClassDetailsViewModel under FundDetailsViewModel and then filter based on Id. Not sure how do I do it ?

Comment: I tried this but it doesnt work       this.FundClass = this.FundClasses.FundDetailsViewModel.array.forEach(x => {
                  x.Id = id;
              });